# How can I determine the PHP version MediaWiki is using?

Tags: php7, mediawiki

Running Ubuntu 19.10 with MediaWiki 1.31.1 installed. I have a wiki that worked well under Ubuntu 19.04 but says
MediaWiki 1.31 internal error

Installing some PHP extensions is required.
Required components

You are missing a required extension to PHP that MediaWiki requires to run. Please install:

```
xml (more information)
```

though xml is loaded for PHP 7.3. But for 7.2 which also is installed xml is not loaded. I guess that MediaWiki uses 7.2. How can I determine the version used? And if it is the wrong, how is it changed?

Comment: Please tell us something about your server configuration. Are you using Apache?

Comment: Yes, I am using Apache. The solution I used was to disable PHP 7,2 with sudo a2dismod php7.2 and see what happened. And then install missing parts of PHP 7.3.

Answer (score 1):

To get what version used, create and open in browser php file with this content

```
<? phpinfo();
```

To install xml for 7.2:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-xml
```

Comment: Sorry but the file does not work. My browser asks what to do with alternatives Open with Chromium and Save file.

Comment: You need to open it from webserver, not in file manager. Like http://localhost/phpinfo.php

Comment: Should it not be "<?php phpinfo(); ?>"

Comment: @TommyPollák closing tag is not necessary

Comment: It is the first php that is missing ...

Comment: @TommyPollák I really skip closing tag at end of php file everyday. Only last in a file